# MS SQL 2005: Any way to temporarily set the system date for a T-SQL script to a different date?

Tags: sql-server-2005, systemtime

We have a bunch of T-SQL scripts dependent on today's date and when they run.  If one doesn't run on the week it should, we end up temporarily setting the system time a day before, run the script, then set it back.

Is there anyway to temporarily set the system date for a script without changing the original script, like when you execute it or only for that session?

Comment: Why can't you change the existing scripts? It seems the only sensible solution to this.

Comment: We don't control the original code.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the actual date in a table / temp table.
THen retrieve or update that date rather then making a call to `GetDate()`.

Comment: Problem is the existing scripts call getdate() and we cannot change the existing scripts.

Comment: @Dr Zim - but if you run the script call getdate and then insert that date in the table you can then check.  If there is a date to use the date in the table rather then getdate.

Comment: Without changing the existing code, how would you get the original code to use the date in a table?

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer by someone else, here I share it: "The date is tied to the OS date and time. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx".

You could refer to this other question [Simulate current date on a SQL Server instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246539/simulate-current-date-on-a-sql-server-instance)